# How to disable only_full_group_by in MySQL or Sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

In Sequelize, how would I do the equivalent of `SET sql_mode=''` to avoid getting the following error?

> `SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'assets.group_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Or, alternatively, how do I change the default configuration of MySQL such that the `sql_mode` is always `''`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

Comment: Great! This seems to have done it! Thanks so much. I will accept this answer once I am allowed to. (Apparently you responded much faster than stackoverflow allows me to accept)

Comment: Thanks it helps me
as it was working perfect before a day today itself it's giving me an error
may i know the reason?

Comment: I always get a permission error: MySQL said: Documentation #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation –

Answer (score 25):

Get the existing sql_mode and remove only the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` value rather than making it completely empty.

```
SELECT @@sql_mode; -- Get the current sql_mode
```

You might get a result as follows;

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Now remove the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from the result and update the sql_mode

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
SET SESSION sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

Now you are done.

Note that SET GLOBAL is to update the global setting which will not take effect until you restart the mysql server or service.
SET SESSION will immediately take this effect on your current session even without restarting mysql server. Therefore, you can use either one or both depending on your requirement.

Alternatively, instead of disabling this setting, from MySQL 5.7 onwards, you can simply modify the query by using `ANY_VALUE` function on whichever the field is throwing error. For example `ANY_VALUE(assets.group_id)` as mentioned in the error message you have posted.

Comment: The ANY_VALUE(assets.group_id) workaround was perfect. Good hack

Comment: I always get a permission error:  MySQL said: Documentation
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation

Answer (score 0):

After following the other answers,
**NOTE THAT** if you change the sql_mode, it will not affect stored procedures. sql_mode gets stored with the SP itself, so you need to **drop and execute SP again** after the sql_mode change